# how to plot 3D partial dependence in GBM

Tags: independence, boosting, partial-effect

I can use the following code to get one-dimensional partial dependence plot. what code can I plot two-variable partial dependence plot, that's the three dimensional figure. Thanks.

plot.gbm(GBMmodel,i.var=4,n.trees=100...)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the R function `persp`.

Here is an example using *diabetes* dataset along with the function `reshape2::acast` to convert a three columns dataframe into a matrix of desired dimension.

We represent the partial dependence plot of the variables *age* and *sex*.

```
library(gbm)
library(reshape2)
data(diabetes, package = 'lars')

y        <- diabetes$y
x        <- diabetes$x
class(x) <- 'matrix'
data     <- data.frame(y, as.data.frame(x))

gbm.model <- gbm::gbm(formula = y ~ . , data = data, distribution = 'gaussian', 
                 shrinkage = 1, bag.fraction = 1, n.trees = 100,
                 interaction.depth = 3, verbose = T, keep.data = F)


partial <- plot(gbm.model, i.var = c(1,2), return.grid = T)

colnames(partial)

mat <- reshape2::acast(data = partial, formula = age ~ sex, value.var = 'y')

persp(x = as.numeric(colnames(mat)), y = as.numeric(rownames(mat)), z=mat,
      zlab = 'partial dependence', xlab = 'sex', ylab = 'age', theta = 30)
```

We obtain the following plot :
[image]

Comment: +1 for minimal reproducible example and the tips of using reshape.

Comment: one thing confusing though, is the sex variable. It is a binary variable, but this partial plot shows how response changes with respect to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide variable positions like so:

```
plot.gbm(GBMmodel, i.var=c(4, 10), n.trees=100)
```

Or variable names:

```
plot.gbm(GBMmodel, i.var=c("Height", "Weight"), n.trees=100)
```

#### Edit:

To make an interactive, three dimensional figure you need a library that supports such plotting:

```
library(plot3Drgl) # if you don't have this, install it!
```

Then save the output of the contour plot:

```
my.plot <- plot.gbm(mod, c(1,4), return.grid = TRUE)
```

Finally, pass in the appropriate columns as x, y, and z to the plot function:

```
points3Drgl(x=my.plot[,1], y=my.plot[,2], z=my.plot[,3])
```

Comment: when i input the code, and press enter, there is "+", could you please show me the full code, thanks

Comment: I missed a quotation. Should work now

Comment: Error in plot.gbm(GBMmodel, i.var = c("Height", "Weight"), n.trees = 100) : 
  Plot variables not used in gbm model fit: HeightWeight

Comment: Alright, @Captain, this is where you have to meet me halfway. I have no idea what variables are in your data set. You can obviously navigate a web site and make a comment. You should be smart enough to know that "height" and "weight" are just examples. You have to put the names of the variables you want to plot in their place.

Comment: plot.gbm(GBMmodel,i.var=c(4,3),n.trees=best.iter) it shows contour, not 3D figure

Answer (score 0):

The [plotmo](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plotmo/index.html)
R package will plot partial dependencies as `persp` plots for all
pairs of variables for any model. For example:

```
library(gbm)
data(mtcars)
set.seed(2016)
mod <- gbm(mpg~., data=mtcars[,1:4], n.minobsinnode=1)
library(plotmo)
plotmo(mod, pmethod="partdep")
```

which gives

[image: plot]

You can specify exactly which variables and variable pairs get plotted
using plotmo's `degree1` and `degree2` arguments.
Additional examples are in the 
[vignette for the plotmo package](http://www.milbo.org/doc/plotmo-notes.pdf).